# how to place colorlegend (corrplot) in graphic

Tags: r, legend, heatmap, correlation, r-corrplot

I am using `corrplot` to create a correlation heatmap, but I don't like the default legend - it is too big. So I was trying to use the `colorlegend()` to add the legend after I create the plot (and disable the default legend with `cl.pos="n"`).

Only problem is that I can't figure out how to change the position of the legend - it ends up on the lower left. Ideally, I could place it on the top right, but I looked through the options for `colorlegend` and plot and can't figure this out.

For example:

```
# load libraries and create color scale
library(corrplot)
library(RColorBrewer)
scalebluered <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "RdBu"))(8)

# get data into correlation matrix
data(mtcars)
cars.matrix <- as.matrix(mtcars[c(2:8)])
cars.corr <- cor(cars.matrix)

# plot it
corrplot(cars.corr, method="shade", shade.col=NA, tl.col="black", 
         tl.srt=45, addgrid.col="black", type="lower", diag=FALSE, cl.pos="n")

# add legend
colorlegend(scalebluered, c(seq(-1,1,.25)), align="l", vertical=TRUE, addlabels=TRUE)
```

output: http://i42.tinypic.com/14wsqc0.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Months later, I revisit this and figure it out.. just add xlim and ylim to define the dimensions of the legend.. super easy!

```
colorlegend(xlim=c(10,15), ylim=c(10,15), scalebluered, c(seq(-1,1,.25)), align="l", vertical=TRUE, addlabels=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

like this? changing `cl.pos="n" to "r"`

```
corrplot(cars.corr, method="shade", shade.col=NA, tl.col="black", 
         tl.srt=45, addgrid.col="black", type="lower", diag=FALSE, cl.pos="r")
```

Comment: not quite because the default legend is as tall as the correlation grid.. I'd like a smaller one.. and the ability to place it where I want.  Ideally, something like this:  http://i44.tinypic.com/350qssm.png