# Color Legend has 0 width when making corrPlot with 1 column

Tags: r, plot, r-corrplot

I am trying to make a corrPlot with one column with one column like this

```
library(corrplot)
mc <- cor(mtcars,mtcars["mpg"])
corrplot(mc, method = "circle")
```

but when I do this the color legend has no width like this:
[1columnCorrPlot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esIaw.png)

You can see the labels for the legend on the right side but the colorbar for the legend is just a line on the right border of the corrplot.

I tried using `cl.ratio =` to adjust this but i has no effect when there is only 1 column(it does have an effect when there are multiple columns).

Does anyone know a way to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Glenn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code for corrplot which you can do by using `fix(corrplot)`, you will notice `cl.ratio` is always multiplied by a variable `mm` to define `xlim` e.g. `xlim <- c(m1 - 0.5 - xlabwidth, m2 + 0.5 + mm * cl.ratio * (cl.pos == "r"))` and `mm` is calculated via:

```
m2 <- max(Pos[, 1])
m1 <- min(Pos[, 1])
mm <- m2 - m1
```

which results in `mm=0` in the 1 column case. You can verify this by saving the `corrplot` function into another file (e.g. `mycorrplot.r`) and name the function `mycorrplot()`. Add these 3 lines following `mm <- m2 - m1`

```
cat("Before:",mm,"\n")
mm <- 1
cat("After:",mm,"\n")
```

Essentially, changing `mm=0` to `mm=1`. Once you have done it, do:

```
source("mycorrplot.r")
mycorrplot(mc, method = "circle", cl.ratio=1)
```

This will allow `cl.ratio` to modify the width of the legend.
[image]

This is just a hack, you should let the `corrplot` maintainer know of this issue.
[https://github.com/taiyun/corrplot]

Another option is to draw your own color legend: see [how to place colorlegend (corrplot) in graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773819/how-to-place-colorlegend-corrplot-in-graphic)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I have let the maintainer know on github. For now I will just add my own color legend.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there and thanks for the bug report.
I just closed the issue in our issue tracker on Github:
https://github.com/taiyun/corrplot/issues/19